# Error using api.update_status method in tweepy using Oauth2

Tags: python-2.7, tweepy

Here is my code:-
I have double checked all the auth parameters.

```
import tweepy


CONSUMER_KEY ='#Omitted - you should not publish your actual key'
CONSUMER_SECRET ='#Omitted - you should not publish your actual secret'
ACCESS_KEY='#Omitted - you should not publish your access key'
ACCESS_SECRET = '#Omitted - you should not publish your access secret'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)

api.update_status('Tweeting from command line')
```

Saved the file in home folder as status.py
after running python status.py follwing error comes:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "status.py", line 14, in <module>
    api.update_status('Tweeting from command line')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-1.10-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 185, in _call
    return method.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-1.10-py2.7.egg/tweepy/binder.py", line 168, in execute
    raise TweepError(error_msg, resp)
tweepy.error.TweepError: Could not authenticate with OAuth.
```

Please, help me out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to authenticate using tweepy, I have an extra line in my code though, it might help for you to change your code to this:

```
import tweepy
from tweepy import OAuthHandler
```

then proceede with the rest of your code. Also add a line in your code to print out to the shell to show your connect as follows:

`print api.me().name`

Make sure the line you see above this is right after `api = tweepy.API(auth)`

Comment: i added the line u said... here is what code looks like now:-

import tweepy

from tweepy import OAuthHandler

CONSUMER_KEY ='#'
CONSUMER_SECRET ='#'
ACCESS_KEY='#'
ACCESS_SECRET = '#'

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
auth.set_access_token(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET)
api = tweepy.API(auth)
print api.me().name
api.update_status('Tweeting from command line')

Comment: here is the error:-

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "newstatus.py", line 13, in <module>
    print api.me().name
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-1.10-py2.7.egg/tweepy/api.py", line 182, in me
    return self.get_user(screen_name=self.auth.get_username())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tweepy-1.10-py2.7.egg/tweepy/auth.py", line 161, in get_username
    raise TweepError("Unable to get username, invalid oauth token!")
tweepy.error.TweepError: Unable to get username, invalid oauth token!

Comment: looks like Tweepy is having a difficult time getting your oAuth token, check up at dev.twitter.com login and make sure everything is exactly correct. Just copy and paste the code in. Also in future its ok to make edits to your original question, this way there is no character limit when making a response.

Comment: i have double checked the keys and secrets... Can u suggest if there are any other possible causes of this error??

Comment: The command `api.status_update('Tweeting from the command line')` I'm thinking might be the error, it looks like in your error message that might be causing an error. Also you might want to try and reset your OAuth token as it is saying its invalid. Other than that I'm sorry I do not know. But lets see what that does and see if we can dope it out.

Comment: hey man... thnx for help... i reset my keys and changed the access permissions to read, write and direct messages... now its wrkn... :) :)

Comment: i am now able to use all the tweepy commands. I want to convert the tweepy objects returned by various api calls into a JSON object. Can you help me out regarding that??

Comment: Glad to hear all is working, on converting things to a JSON object my friend I am of no use, sorry about that. Just post it as another question or check over the stackoverflow first and you should be good to roll!

Answer (score 3):

I received this error under the same conditions - using tweepy, all of my keys/secrete were copy and pasted correctly. The problem was the time on my server. After running `ntpdate -b pool.ntp.org` I was to use tweepy just fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `api.update_status(status='Tweeting from command line')`. It helped me.