# python-tweepy with oauth -error code 301-failed to fetch username

Tags: python, twitter, oauth, tweepy

I am new to python and trying to make a program which pots tweets on a particular user's timeline
I am clueless on debugging this. Not much help online. This looks simple enough, not sure why it is not working.
Any help will be greatly appreciated. I am using python 2.7.3

```
consumer_token = ''
consumer_secret = ''
access_token = ''
access_secret = ''

auth = tweepy.OAuthHandler(consumer_token,consumer_secret)
auth.set_access_token(access_token,access_secret)

api  = tweepy.API(auth)
print api.me().name
api.update_status('Hello -tweepy + oauth!')
```

I tried suggestions from this post 
[Error using api.update_status method in tweepy using Oauth2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11468205/error-using-api-update-status-method-in-tweepy-using-oauth2)

```
File "C:\Python27\tweet_fetch.py", line 22, in twitter_fetch
    print api.me().name
File "C:\Python27\Lib\tweepy-1.2\tweepy\api.py", line 303, in me
    raise TweepError('Failed to fetch username: %s' % e)
TweepError: Failed to fetch username: Twitter error response: status code = 301
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a [bug](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy/issues/12) in tweepy-1.2 version. Just upgrade to the latest (2.0) tweepy version:

```
pip install tweepy --upgrade
```

or

```
pip uninstall tweepy
pip install tweepy
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't have pip installed. But, I manually downloaded tweepy library and updated it. Auth is working now. Thanks a ton!